# I use Ubuntu, Kate, gedit, git (command-line), Qt Creator, Nautilus, CodeXL. What's creating these ghost files?

Tags: git, ubuntu, qt-creator, nautilus, kate

In my source tree often files like `main.qml` get copied into files named like `main.qml.q8JDW9` (which also sometimes have a "lock" icon in Nautilus). Then at some point these copies disappear as randomly as they have appeared.

I use the tools enumerated in the question title. Which one of them (or other) could be creating these "ghost" files and why?

Comment: Maybe git temp files?

Comment: Do you use 'git add .' instead of specific files often?

Comment: I don't think git would create these files I imagine it's Qt Creator hmm...

Comment: related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901152/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-garbage-files-that-qt-creator-auto-generates-and-ho

Comment: @PhilipKirkbride: "Do you use 'git add .' instead of specific files often?" - yes, I do.

Comment: @StefanMonov Yep been there use to use Qt creator and git was a nightware. Now I always specify files specially. Do you have a good gitignore file for Qt? Like this one https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Qt.gitignore